# orchard cms Visual Studio team services

Tags: orchardcms, azure-devops

We have a number of Orchard projects that we want to get on Continuous integration using Visual studio team services and octopus deploy but its proving to be a headache (Like most things in Orchard)

In the build step we are running the orchard.proj file with the target precompiled (/t:precompiled)

Is anyone aware of any good documentation that can help us achieve our goal or have any tips?

Many thanks

Comment: How is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Building-and-deploying-Orchard-from-a-source-code-drop/) article, you can run **build precompiled** command (build.cmd file is existing in project/solution folder) to build project (I made a test with [Orchard 1.10.1](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/releases/tag/1.10.1)). So you can add Command Line task/step to your build definition to run **build precompiled** command.

To deploy project to IIS, you could use IIS Web App Deployment task. (You need to install [IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp), then add IIS Web App Deployment task/step to your build definition)